# How to create data model dynamically

Tags: javascript

I have this Json data I get from server in javascript

```
var mydata = JSON.parse('["X","Y","Z"]');
```

Below I have the following data model in javascript..

```
var mySchemasList = {
    schemas: [new SelectSchemaModel("A", false),
              new SelectSchemaModel("B", false),
              new SelectSchemaModel("C", false)
             ]
};
```

I want to create this model dynamically by getting data ('A','B','C') from mydata..

Any help is sincerely appreciated..

Thanks

Comment: You need to have your JavaScript to talk to your back end in whatever protocol it supports.

Comment: I suggest to make rest based web service that return data(in the form of JSON/XML) and via javascript call that webservice and then from JSOn create the respective model.

Comment: @Innovation I can send json data from backend but I need help in creating the model from JSON in javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just do something like the following?

```
var i
var mySchemaList = {schemas:[]}; 
for (i = 0; i < mydata.length; i++) {
    mySchemaList.schemas.push( new SelectSchemaModel(mydata[i], false) );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, objects and arrays are accessed using the `.` or `[]` operators. The following two lines does exactly the same thing:

```
mySchemasList.schemas;
mySchemasList['schemas'];
```

Also, each member of an object or array act like a variable on its own. So you can assign values, objects or arrays to them:

```
mySchemasList = {};
```

When a variable (or property) is declared but not assigned anything its value is `undefined`. So you can check simply by:

```
if (mySchemasList === undefined) mySchemasList = {};
```

Alternatively you can use `||` short circuiting since `undefined` is considered false:

```
mySchemasList = mySchemasList || {};
```

putting this all together, the following two examples does exactly the same thing.

Example 1:

```
var mySchemasList = {
    schemas : []
}
```

Example 2:

```
var mySchemasList = {};
mySchemasList.schemas = [];
```

Now that you've created an array at `mySchemasList.schemas` you can start pushing other objects into it:

```
mySchemasList.schemas.push(new SelectSchemaModel("A", false));
mySchemasList.schemas.push(new SelectSchemaModel("B", false));
mySchemasList.schemas.push(new SelectSchemaModel("C", false));
```

Wrapping it up in a for loop parsing the JSON data, you'd do this:

```
var mydata = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);
for (var i=0; i<mydata.length; i++) {
    mySchemasList.schemas.push(new SelectSchemaModel(mydata[i],false));
}
```